# MBR2GPT /validate failed

Tags: windows-10, mbr, gpt

I have an SSD that is currently MBR. I want to convert it to GPT to use UEFI mode instead of BIOS, so I can use windows 11. I did `MBR2BPT /validate /disk:0` in windows recovery mode cmd, and it failed. Here's what it looks like:

```
X:\windows\system32>mbr2gpt /validate /disk:0
MBR2GPT: Attempting to calidate disk 0
MBR2GPT: Retrieving layout of disk
MBR2GPT: Validating layout, disk sector size is: 512 bytes
Disk layout validation failed for disk 0

X:\windows\system32>
```

Disk management:

[image: Disk mgmt]

The "1.95 GB Unallocated" is there because I shrinked 2000 MB before doing /validate, according to some other posts.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Your disk has an extended partition, which makes it ineligible to use MBR2GPT, you would have to delete the extended partition to use MBR2GPT.  My answer to the duplicate question, applies to this question, despite the fact the actual reasons are different since I provided the requirements for MBR2GPT in the answer itself.

Comment: So do you mean in order for me to convert it to GPT, I need to move everything in D to C, and then delete D?

Comment: The end effect is that you will have to delete the extended partition.  How you get to that effect is entirely up to you.  *You also have 4 partitions, and the requirement, is you can't have more than 3.* Which is literally the same reason as the duplicate question.